# How do I share a printer that is attached to a Fedora computer?

Tags: windows, linux, fedora, printer, network-printer

I have a computer running Fedora 17 with a Xerox Phaser 6360N attached to it.

I need to share that printer to a LAN computer running Windows 7. How do I do this? Preferably without Samba.

Comment: You can just use CUPS, without SAMBA

Comment: @ernie How? I would prefer to just use CUPS.

Comment: Ack, sorry I missed you asking.  Here's a little write-up on it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS_printer_sharing#Linux_server_-_Windows_client ; Basically, set up CUPS and then connect via the CUPS port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use Samba and don't be scared of it. It served me very honest back in the old days.

You can start reading right away from:
http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-File_and_Print_Servers.html#samba-rgs-overview

I can bet things didn't change a lot since Fedora 15. And Fedora 17 Deployment guide doesn't exist, neither for Fedora 16. Probably because nothing has changed on this topic.

Comment: OK, I will try it... Hope it works.